# MySQL query enhanced performance depend on date

Tags: php, mysql, database, innodb

```
Name  Type              Collation   Null    Default     
1     sms_id            int(7)      None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
2     users_id          int(5)      NULL    NULL    
3     sms_number        varchar(9)  No      None        
4     sms_amount        varchar(7)  No      None        
6     server_id         tinyint(2)  Yes     NULL        
7     sms_device        varchar(1)  No      None        
8     special_id        int(6)      Yes     NULL        
9     sms_ip            varchar(32) No      None        
10    sms_adddate       timestamp   No      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

i have this table , that record sms sent from my website 
i want to calculate some data  such as number of sent sms and sum of amount of this sms between two date  for each user,but when i execute  my query it take long time to done form 20-30 seconds because i have a millions of records

this is my mysql query

```
select *,
(select count(sms_id) from sms where sms_adddate>11-11-2012 and sms_adddate<11-11-2013 and sms.users_id=users.users_id limit 1 ) as sms_count,
(select sum(sms_amount) from sms where
 sms_adddate>11-11-2012 and sms_adddate<11-11-2013 and
 sms.users_id=users.users_id limit 1) as sms_amount
 from users limit 10
```

primary key :sms_id
foreign key :users_id,server_id,spicial_id

all of my tables is InnoDB engine and i have already do relations between it.

what i can do to speed up this query?
is it wrong to add index to sms_amount and sms_adddate or what?

Comment: indexes should be on columns which you use to find records... ones that appear in the where part. so, for sms_adddate, yes, it's a good idea

Comment: what kind of indexes can do .. and if it good to add to two column can i do that separate or together .. i mean for each column i do this or all together in same index @naveed-hasan

Comment: @hazem Judging by this query, it looks like you'd want a multi-column index across `sms_adddate` and `user_id`

Comment: @colin-morelli is it right to add multi-column index or single?

Comment: @hazem It depends on the situation. If you will always be querying for dates and users together, then a multi-column index will likely yield the best performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two sub-queries in your query, so you walk two times the sms list. Try with this, I think it should take the half of the time:

```
SELECT users.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT sms.sms_id) AS sms_count,
       SUM(sms.sms_amount) AS sms_amount
FROM users
     INNER JOIN sms
         ON users.users_id = sms.users_id
         AND sms.sms_adddate>11-11-2012 and sms.sms_adddate<11-11-2013
WHERE 1
GROUP BY users.users_id
# Optionally (extra time consumption): ORDER BY sms_count DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Also, the fields sms.sms_adddate and sms.users_id shoud has their indexes to speed up the filters that the query uses.

You can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` if you also want to see the users without sms in that period... (all users indeed)

Comment: i I've copied your query, but it took much longer than my query.

Comment: Did you add the sms_adddate index? It is important (Edit: Also sms.users_id should has an index too)

Comment: You could use sms_adddate BETWEEN here. It would be a bit more readable.

Comment: I did not do it, I'm afraid that the process takes a long time, and will affect the rest of the users

Comment: With a millions of records it will takes a long time for sure, although at the end it will be very good for that query. You could try it with a copy of the DB first (a develop environment or something like that). I've done a lot of experiments with indexes and filters, and I can tell you that there is a HUGE difference.